# Docker Swarm containers cannot connect to each other

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm trying to repeat "Deploy a stack to a swarm" tutorial, but with a twist: one container is to run on one instance and one on another. Consider the following files (especially docker-compose.yml):

## docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    image: 127.0.0.1:5000/stackdemo
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - data
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == primary]
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    networks:
      data:
        aliases:
          - redis
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == secondary]

networks:
  data:
    driver: overlay
```

## app.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis
    
app = Flask(__name__)
redis = Redis(host='redis.docker', port=6379)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    count = redis.incr('hits')
    return 'Hello World! I have been seen {} times.\n'.format(count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, debug=True)
```

## Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.4-alpine
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

## requirements.txt

```
flask
redis
```

I'm trying this on t2.nano AWS instances using Ubuntu 22.04 AMI. The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 539, in connect
    sock = self._connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 566, in _connect
    socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 537, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2334, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2320, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1766, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2317, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1840, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1743, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1838, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1824, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/code/app.py", line 9, in hello
    count = redis.incr('hits')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1367, in incr
    return self.incrby(name, amount)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1376, in incrby
    return self.execute_command('INCRBY', name, amount)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 836, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1073, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 544, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to redis.docker:6379. Name does not resolve.
```

Beforehand, I installed Docker via its official repository (not the one from the distribution), I set up a registry, built and pushed the image and initialized the swarm using --advertise-addr. Here's how I checked whether both containers are running:

```
# docker stack ps stackdemo
ID             NAME                IMAGE                             NODE        DESIRED STATE   CURRENT STATE            ERROR     PORTS
8l3d77uvncjz   stackdemo_redis.1   redis:alpine                      secondary   Running         Running 19 minutes ago             
s1iwncohtjwn   stackdemo_web.1     127.0.0.1:5000/stackdemo:latest   primary     Running         Running 19 minutes ago
```

I also tried to rule out a firewall problem:

[image: a screenshot of AWS security group description]

I'm out of theories. What else should I check?

Comment: First, verify this works when all containers are run on the same node. Then don't look at firewall rules in one place to verify it's not a firewall. Run tcpdump on the source and destination, and match each outgoing connection with an incoming one on the other node. Focus on the overlay networking ports.

Comment: @BMitch the problem is that it's not even a connection error - it's a DNS problem before that

Comment: Please verify that you've read and tested the first sentence of my comment. The rest depends on that.

Comment: @BMitch I confirm that I did.

Comment: Did it work or did it still fail? Show the results. You can exclude a significant chunk of debugging by isolating the issue. If it doesn't work on a one node swarm cluster, does it work with docker compose instead of swarm. If so, you can completely rephrase the question and retag it to focus on the problem.

Comment: your networking settings seem redundant. You dont need to create a network yourself. And you dont need to add redis under the alias redis. Both things happens automatically.

Comment: @TheFool right, that's a side effect of my experimenting.

Answer (score 2):

After debugging using tcpdump just like BMitch suggested, I found two things, not sure which helped:

- tcpdump checksums seemed broken, so I used various ethtool commands to disable them,
- **I added `--data-path-addr  $( curl ifconfig.me/ip )` to `docker swarm join` command**

I think it's the latter that helped - the default eth0 IP visible via the SSH was a local address and that might have been breaking the connections. It seems to work now.

Also, it turned out that I can reduce my docker-compose.yml to this:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
    
services:
  web:
    image: 127.0.0.1:5000/stackdemo
      build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == primary]
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == secondary]
```

The hostname in app.py should be `redis`.

Comment: Pretty sure invalid checksums are normal for those packets, I forget the exact reason why.